# return UITimer value into mapView - Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, uislider, mkannotation, mkannotationview

When I click on a UIButton, the `@IBAction func pressPlay()` starts which, using a timer, moves the thumb of the slider (UISlider) every second.
The initial value of the slider is 0.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,SCSEarthquakesHandler,SCSPublicSeismometersHandler
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var sliderTime: UISlider!

    @IBAction func pressPlay(_ sender: Any)
    {
         let calendar2 = Calendar.current
        let today = Date()
        var cnt = Int(sliderTime.value)
        let play = UIImage(named: "play")
        let pause = UIImage(named: "pause")
        let format = DateFormatter()
        playButton.setImage(play, for: .normal)
        if control == true && Int(sliderTime.value) < 0
        { //set to play
            control = false
            playButton.setImage(pause, for: .normal)
            if Int(sliderTime.value) < 0
            {
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1,repeats: true)
                { [self]t in //ogni secondo questo timer cambia il valore dell'alpha del pin che sta vibrando
                    
                    if cnt < 0
                    {
                        cnt = Int(self.sliderTime.value)
                        self.sliderTime.value += 1
                        let newDate2 = calendar2.date(byAdding: .day, value: Int(self.sliderTime.value), to:today)! //sottraggo alla data attuale il vlaore dello slider per tornare indietro nel tempo
                        format.dateStyle = .medium // "MM/GG/AAAA"
                        self.labelTime.text = "\(format.string(from: newDate2))"
                    }else if cnt == 0{
                        removeSeismometers = false
                        playButton.setImage(play, for: .normal)
                        timer!.invalidate()
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if control == false && Int(sliderTime.value) < 0 { //mette in pausa
            removeSeismometers = true
            playButton.setImage(play, for: .normal)
            control = true
            timer!.invalidate()
        }
    }
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        print(Int(sliderTime.value))
     ...
    }

}
```

I tried to recall the value of the slider inside the `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {` but despite the slider has no value 0, when I go to print it in here it always returns value 0. Why?
I tried something ... I defined a global variable and initialized it to 0. I called it inside the mapView (...) function and increased it by 1. I noticed that it increments it every second (minus of a second). So I don't understand why sliderTime.value doesn't return the current value to me, but instead always 0.
How can I have the value of the slider printed during this animation?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not use a slider to store a value. (View objects display information, not save it.) You should set an instance variable in your class, and have a didSet method on that instance variable udpate the slider.

Second, if you set your variable cnt to 0, it will never get incremented. your timer's closure has an if statement `if cnt < 0`. That will never be true if `cnt == 0`. You need to change that if statement to `if cnt <= 0`. That will work if cnt is zero **or less**, which is what you want.

Comment: Hi Duncan! First of all, thanks for your reply. The pressPlay function works well, because it's a similar toggle function that displays two images on the button (play and pause) and moves the cursor.
My only problem is to return the slider value inside the mapView function. The current value of the slider I get it with sliderTime.value (to have it as an integer I do Int (sliderTime.value)). This value inside the mapView always remains 0, although the value is different.

Comment: I don't see how that function can work if cnt is initialized with a value of 0. Your `if` statement will always fail because cnt will never be **less than** zero.

Comment: the variable cnt is not initialized to zero. I initialized it as a global variable and didn't put the code here on stackoverflow. The function works great, I have tested it many times! The problem is far from it, that is it does not print the correct slider content.

Comment: Please when you can, can you help me? If you want, I'll send you an email with a sample video, because I'm going crazy...!

Comment: You're providing incomplete information. I suggest putting a breakpoint in your timer closure, and/or adding print statements that log the value of cnt. I don't see how your timer code can "work great" since you have an if statement `if cnt<0` which will never be true unless cnt is **negative**. And if cnt is less than zero, that code will increment it until it is ≥ 0, and then stop working.

Comment: Cnt is initially zero as it takes the initial value of the slider, which is 0. The slider ranges from 0 to -31 (the days of a month). Go back n days by dragging the cursor with your finger, then when you click on the button the pressPlay function is triggered which makes sure that if cnt is less than 0 (true because I moved the slider, and I went "back in time" ) starts a timer that every second moves the slider by one position and returns it to 0, i.e. the current date.
I edited the code including the code I omitted.

Comment: I've read on other posts on stackoverflow, that in these cases I should update my annotation, for example remove it and add it again ... is there a way to update the viewFor?